# Hover doesn't function properly or at all

Tags: html, css, hover

On my website I have a navigation bar that I want to change colors to a red tint when I hover over it (right now I have it set to black). However, the CSS doesn't do anything at all when I hover over the navigation bar.

HTML:

```
    <div id="topNav">
        <ul class="nav">
<li class="home"><a href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo url('/about'); ?>">About Us</a></li>
<?php
if(!Auth::LoggedIn())
{
    // Show these if they haven't logged in yet
?>
    <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo url('/registration'); ?>">Careers</a></li>
<?php
}
else
{
    // Show these items only if they are logged in
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/profile'); ?>">Pilot Center</a></li>

<?php
}
?>
<li class="home"><a href="<?php echo url('/ops'); ?>">Operations</a></li>
<li class="home"><a href="<?php echo url('/forums'); ?>">Forums</a></li>
<li class="home"><a href="<?php echo url('/contact'); ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo url('/acars') ?>">Live Map</a></li>
<?php echo $MODULE_NAV_INC;?>
<?php
if(Auth::LoggedIn())
{
    if(PilotGroups::group_has_perm(Auth::$usergroups, ACCESS_ADMIN))
    {
        echo '<li><a href="'.fileurl('/admin').'">Admin Center</a></li>';
    }
?>


<li><a href="<?php echo url('/logout'); ?>">Log Out</a></li>
<?php
}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#topNav { font-size: 14px; padding-top: 10px; width: 970px; margin: auto; height: 50px; background-color: #000; }

#topNav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; }
#topNav ul:hover { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; }

#topNav ul li { height: 37px; float: left; padding: 0px; font: bold 12px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#topNav ul li:hover { height: 37px; float: left; padding: 0px; font: bold 12px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#topNav ul li a { padding: 0 18px; height: 37px; float: left; text-decoration: none; display: block; color: #ffffff; font: 14px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#topNav ul li a:hover { padding: 0 18px; height: 37px; float: left; text-decoration: none; display: block; color: #ffffff; font: 14px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.nav, .nav ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.nav { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; z-index: 1000; position: relative; }
.nav li { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; }
.nav li a, .nav li a:link, .nav li a:active, .nav li a:visited { font: bold 1.22em/25px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #959595; display: block; padding: 0 9px; text-decoration: none; }

.nav ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; width: 150px; position: absolute; top: -999em; left: -1px; }
.nav ul li { border: 0; float: none; }
.nav ul a { padding-right: 20px; width: 150px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Comment: Please post your html as it as rendered (right click the page and go to "view source" or similar. It is difficult to reproduce your problem if the posted html is littered with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing CSS to actually set it to hover. You need something like

```
#topNav:hover {background: red}
```

Comment: Had to do `#topNav ul li:hover`.